# All The Images In A Folder in a Dropdown Menu

Tags: php

I want to list all the images in a folder in a selectable dropdown menu using PHP. (With image name as label).
When I select an image and save the form, I need to retrieve the URL (or just the image name with extension) to show it using `<img src=""/>`.

Is that possible? If yes, how can I do that?

Regards

Comment: read about [directoryiterator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php)

Answer (score 0):

[`glob()`](http://www.php.net/glob) can be used to grab the image files in a directory. You can then loop over them to create your `<select>` element.

```
$images = glob("images/*.{jpg,gif,png}", GLOB_BRACE);

echo '<select name="image">';
foreach($images as $image)
{
    echo '<option>' . basename($image) . '</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is very possible.

You could use the [glob function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) to do something like this:

```
$dropdown = "<select name='image'>\n";
foreach (glob('*.{gif,jpg}', GLOB_BRACE) as $filename) {
    $dropdown .= "<option value='$filename'>pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_FILENAME)</option>\n"
}
$dropdown .= "</select>\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

Only names In Drop down will not solve the problem. As by name we are not sure which images is being attached. For that we need to display Images in drop down options as will. For this purpose you can use this Jquery plugin http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/jquery-image-dropdown this will display image in drop down as will.